# Return a certain value based on the contents of a string

Tags: c, string

For example if `c[20] = "Six of Spades"`, then 6 is returned, if `c[20] = "Nine of Hearts"`, then 9 is returned, and so on. So the value returned is based only on the first word in the string. Is there a simple method to do such thing?

Answer (score 5):

```
int cardValue(char* card)
{    
    char* values[] = {"One", "Two", "Three" ... };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(values) / sizeof(values[0]); i++)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(values[i]);
        if (strncmp(values[i], card, len) == 0)
        {
           return i + 1;
        }
    } 
    return -1; // error
}
```

You may need some special case handling when you get to Ace, King, Queen etc.

Comment: @chux: On the contrary, if `values[i]` is `"Six"` and `card` is `"Six of Spades"`, then `strncmp()` here has the useful property of giving a correct answer to the question, when `strcmp()` has not.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths  
I stand corrected. (although I would used `size_t len` to avoid unneeded type changes.) Of course if the deck had a ["Fourteen of hearts"](http://www.djmcadam.com/six-handed-five-hundred.html) that might conflict with `"Four" with 7 handed 500 ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**No**

You can implement it yourself though, by fishing the first word from the string (e.g. with `strtok()`), and then based on that substring, return the corresponding number.